# bash function output to pipe

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

I made a bash function to beautify `svn` output, this function show logs one line per commit, it is great! I like it, but if I use it with pipe it does not work.
You can find it on [github svn-beautify](https://github.com/fabiov/svn-beautify/blob/master/svn-beautify.sh)

```
$ svn -log -l 2
r22  fabio  2014-03-27 12:38:10 +0100 (gio, 27 mar 2014)  1 line  Some comments
r23  fabio  2014-03-27 13:35:17 +0100 (gio, 27 mar 2014)  1 line  Some comments
```

it would be nice if I could use it with `| grep`.

Comment: What happens when you pipe into grep? What's the problem?

Comment: I put svn function into my .bashrc so when I use
`svn log -l 10` 
I see output from my function instead svn standard command, but if I use 
`svn log -l 10 | grep foo`
or 
`svn log -l 10 | cat`
i see output from standartd svn command

I would like use `|grep` from my svn function

Comment: Your command is producing color escape sequence. Grepping for e.g. "Some comments" won't work, because it's really "<blue>Some<black> comments".

Comment: ok, i don't care color into grep command, but if I use 
`| grep foo` grep don't use output from my function (one line per commit) but from standard svn (more lines per commit).

Comment: There are some other things wrong with your script—e.g., you ought not be using `which`, you probably want `command`. I suggest you may want to ask for comments on [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Another tip: don't use `eval $(which svn) ...` -- instead use `command svn ...`

Comment: ok, thanks, i replace `eval $(which svn) ...` with `command svn ...` but why is better????

Comment: Please edit your question to make it self-contained. That means posting (the relevant parts of) your code here, and explaining why it doesn't work (everything you posted in the comments here).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compose bash functions using pipes?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114121/how-to-compose-bash-functions-using-pipes)

Answer (score 3):

You have this:

```
if [ "$SVN_COLOR" != "always" ] && ( 
        [ $NOCOL = 1 ] || [ "$SVN_COLOR" = "never" ] || [ ! -t 1 ]
)
```

It's the `[ ! -t 1 ]` test that is causing your function to return too early. When you pipe your function into a pipe, stdout (file descriptor `1`) is *not* a terminal.

Comment: Beat me to it. Indeed this is exactly why. You may want to mention the potential problems with piping colored output, due to color being escape codes mixed in with the output.

Comment: I decided to leave the fix as an exercise for the author of the function :)

Comment: GREAT it works !!!!
I put 
`if [ "$SVN_COLOR" != "always" ] && ([ $NOCOL = 1 ] || [ "$SVN_COLOR" = "never" ])`

but what changes?

Comment: The original function is [svn-color](https://github.com/jmlacroix/svn-color/blob/master/svn-color.sh) i just modify log and diff case.

Comment: I assume the original author did not want to pollute the svn output with colour codes if the output was going to be parsed by some program: colour codes are intended for human eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely is not a general bash-function-with-pipes-problem.

```
~$ x() { ls "$@" ; }
~$ x / | cat -n | head
     1  bin
     2  boot
     3  dev
     4  etc
     5  home
     6  initrd.img
     7  initrd.img.old
     8  lib
     9  lib32
    10  lib64
```

...isn't there a special Stackexchange site for codereview? Maybe ask there?